# Fragment Themes

Tags: android-fragments, android-theme, android-styles

I have a fragment that can be used in two different places in the app.  Depending on where the fragment is used I need it to look differently.

The changes mostly consist of text color, background, and certain elements visibility.  I would like to be able to use the same layout and fragment but have it themed differently depending on where it is used.  I cannot rely on theming the activities differently because the fragment might need to be loaded in both themes within the same activity.

Is there anyway to accomplish this? Also I know that in 5.0 we can now specify a theme attribute on any view.  Is this functionality found in the appcompat lib?

Any solution needs to work on api 16 and up.

Thanks,
Nathan

Answer (score 0):

You could use ContextThemeWrapper:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html

In your onCreateView you can

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final Context contextThemeWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.yourtheme);
        LayoutInflater localInflater = inflater.cloneInContext(contextThemeWrapper);
        return localInflater.inflate(R.layout.yourfragment, container, false);
    }
```